# Passing fortran allocatable arrays to C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I know this has been asked in various forms before but I can't find anything matching my exact case.

kernel.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" void ckernel(int i, int* ptr) {
  //std::cout << i << std::endl;
  //std::cout << ptr[i] << std::endl;
  std::cout << ptr[0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << ptr[1] << std::endl;
  std::cout << ptr[2] << std::endl;
  //ptr[i] = ptr[i] + 5;
}
```

main.f90

```
module util
  use iso_c_binding
  interface
    subroutine ckernel(i, x) bind(c)
      use iso_c_binding
      implicit none
      integer(c_int), value, intent(in) :: i
      integer(c_int), allocatable, target :: x(:)
    end subroutine
  end interface
end module

program test
  use iso_c_binding
  use util
  integer(c_int), allocatable, target :: x(:)
  allocate(x(3))
  x(1) = 1
  x(2) = 2
  x(3) = 3

  call ckernel(2, x)

end program
```

Makefile (There's a reason why I am linking with c++ compiler, I don't think this is an issue)

```
all: driver

main.o : main.f90
        ifort -c main.f90

CLFAGS=-g -O2
kernel.o: kernel.cpp
        icpc ${CFLAGS} -c kernel.cpp

driver: main.o kernel.o
        icpc ${CFLAGS} -o driver main.o kernel.o -lifcore -lifcoremt -lifcore -lifport -qopenmp /soft/compilers/intel-2019/compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.243/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin/for_main.o

clean:
        rm -f main.o kernel.o driver
```

The pointer does not get passed correctly to C++

```
./driver
18763904
0
4
```

The problem must be the way I define my interface because this works (changing the name of ckernel to ckernel_):

```
!  use iso_c_binding
!  interface
!    subroutine ckernel(i, x) bind(c)
!      use iso_c_binding
!      implicit none
!      integer(c_int), value, intent(in) :: i
!      integer(c_int), allocatable, target :: x(:)
!    end subroutine
!  end interface
!end module

program test
  use iso_c_binding
!  use util
  integer(c_int), allocatable, target :: x(:)
  allocate(x(3))
  x(1) = 1
  x(2) = 2
  x(3) = 3

  call ckernel(2, x)

end program
```

```
./driver
1
2
3
```

Comment: As you are allocating the array on the Fortran side why areyou using the allocatable attribute in the interface? You will only need that if you are going to do memory management of the array by the C side (sorry, I need a holiday).

Comment: @IanBush I was just trying to match the attributes of the declaration. removing allocatable has no effect

Comment: A target variable is not a simple pointer

Comment: The allocatable is definitely wrong here. And (:) is wrong as well. It has been discussed before. Use just `(*)`.